# How to display a custom block inside a custom page

Tags: blocks

I have a custom page (in code) already built and routed. It's running a single function that renders some content to the page. I also have a custom block (in code) that I need to reference or include in the custom page.

I am not sure what the best way to combine or reference the block from the custom page.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using and why is your page and block done in code?

Comment: Technically you could do it through the blocks UI, but sounds like you're building a custom module where you don't want to user to have to do steps to get it on your custom page. Can't help you any further until you tell us your Drupal version.

Comment: Drupal 8.3.3 - I think I need to create a view, then reference the functions from there.